# RTK Query cannot set tag id

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

I am trying to setup RTK Query and have some troubles with defining a tag-id.

No matter what I try, I cannot seem to make the "Timeseries" tag work with an id.

Here is my api:

```
export type GetTimeseriesProps = {
    datasource: InsightshubDataSource
    from: string,
    to: string
}
export const valuesightApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: "valuesightQuery",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: import.meta.env.VITE_VALUESIGHT_BACKEND_URL }),
    tagTypes: ['Dashboard', 'Timeseries'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getDashboardById: builder.query<Dashboard, void>({
            query: (id) => `/vsapi/Dashboard/${id}`,
            providesTags: (result, error, arg) => [
                { type: 'Dashboard', id: Number(arg) },
            ]
        }),
        getTimeseriesFromTo: builder.query<TimeSeriesData[], GetTimeseriesProps>({
            query: (props) => ({
                url: `/vsapi/Timeseries/${props.datasource.assetId}/${props.datasource.aspectName}/${props.datasource.variableName}`,
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    from: props.from,
                    to: props.to
                }
            }),
            providesTags: (result, error, arg) => [{
                type: 'Timeseries',
                id: String(arg.datasource.assetId)
            }]
        }),

    }),
});
```

Whenever I make a new Timeseries query, it automatically gets the entire parameter (arg) object as id, NOT just the arg.datasource.assetId.

This works fine with the dashboard however as I can see in the RTK Query tab in the extension:

[image]

So the same thing happens if I dont provide an Id, so it seems like it cant parse the args for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The tags are only used for query/mutation endpoint validations.

See:

- **[Cache Behavior](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/cache-behavior)**, specifically [Re-fetching after mutations by invalidating cache tags](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/cache-behavior#re-fetching-after-mutations-by-invalidating-cache-tags)
- **[Automated Re-fetching](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching)**, specifically [Cache tags](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching#cache-tags)

The query endpoints can [provide specific tags](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#providestags), and the mutation endpoints can [invalidate](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#invalidatestags) them and trigger queries to automatically re-run.

What you are looking at in the Redux-Devtools however ***are not*** the tags, these are the query cache keys. The cache keys are part of Redux-Toolkit Query's "publish/subscribe" mechanism.

See [`serializeQueryArgs`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#serializequeryargs):

> By default, this function will take the query arguments, sort object
> keys where applicable, stringify the result, and concatenate it with
> the endpoint name. This creates a cache key based on the combination
> of arguments + endpoint name (ignoring object key order), such that
> calling any given endpoint with the same arguments will result in the
> same cache key.

Here I've marked the provided cache tags in green, and the query cache keys in red. You can see the current queries and subscriptions using the query cache keys, and the provided tags map specific tags to specific query cache keys.

```js
checkTour: build.query<Tour, string>({
  query: (tourId) =>
    generatePath("/api/tourInfo/:tourId", { tourId }),
  providesTags: (result, error, tourId) => [
    { type: "tour", id: tourId.toUpperCase() },
  ],
}),
```

[image]
[image]

You can provide your own custom cache keys however, using the `createApi`'s [`serializeQueryArgs`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#serializequeryargs) function (*description quoted above*), or each endpoint's [`serializeQueryArgs`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#serializequeryargs-1) function (*below*).

> Can be provided to return a custom cache key value based on the query
> arguments.
>
> This is primarily intended for cases where a non-serializable value is
> passed as part of the query arg object and should be excluded from the
> cache key. It may also be used for cases where an endpoint should only
> have a single cache entry, such as an infinite loading / pagination
> implementation.
>
> Unlike the `createApi` version which can only return a string, this
> per-endpoint option can also return an an object, number, or boolean.
> If it returns a string, that value will be used as the cache key
> directly. If it returns an object / number / boolean, that value will
> be passed to the built-in `defaultSerializeQueryArgs`. This simplifies
> the use case of stripping out args you don't want included in the
> cache key.